# cURL on windows 10 Problems

Tags: curl, windows-10

Would somebody please help me?
I installed it and tested the API of coinbase and it was OK

```
 F:\curl\bin>curl https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/spot?currency=USD
 {"data":{"base":"BTC","currency":"USD","amount":"7268.29"},"warnings": 
 [{"id":"missing_version","message":"Please supply API version (YYYY-MM-DD) 
 as CB-VERSION 
 header","url":"https://developers.coinbase.com/api#versioning"}]}
```

But when using cURL on some other APIs , unfortunately cURL sucks and for example , when I'm the API of some website with these lines :

```
curl -X POST \
--header "X-Backtory-Authentication-Id: 5b0baf0de4b0988b2cea3438" \
--header "X-Backtory-Authentication-Key: 5b0baf0de4b0f80a3dc1d30a" \
-F "username=divar" \
-F "password=123" \
https://api.backtory.com/auth/login
```

the result is :

```
 F:\curl\bin> curl -X POST \
 Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 
 'X'.
At line:1 char:6
+ curl -X POST \
+      ~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], 
ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

PS F:\curl\bin>     --header "X-Backtory-Authentication-Id: 
5b0baf0de4b0988b2cea3438" \
At line:1 char:7
+     --header "X-Backtory-Authentication-Id: 5b0baf0de4b0988b2cea3438" ...
+       ~
Missing expression after unary operator '--'.
At line:1 char:7
+     --header "X-Backtory-Authentication-Id: 5b0baf0de4b0988b2cea3438" ...
+       ~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'header' in expression or statement.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], 
ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator

PS F:\curl\bin>     --header "X-Backtory-Authentication-Key: 
5b0baf0de4b0f80a3dc1d30a" \
At line:1 char:7
+     --header "X-Backtory-Authentication-Key: 5b0baf0de4b0f80a3dc1d30a ...
+       ~
Missing expression after unary operator '--'.
At line:1 char:7
+     --header "X-Backtory-Authentication-Key: 5b0baf0de4b0f80a3dc1d30a ...
+       ~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'header' in expression or statement.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], 
 ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator

PS F:\curl\bin>     -F "username=divar" \
 -F : The term '-F' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
 script file, or operable program. Check the
 spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
 correct and try again.
 At line:1 char:5
 +     -F "username=divar" \
 +     ~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-F:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS F:\curl\bin>     -F "password=123" \
-F : The term '-F' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:5
+     -F "password=123" \
+     ~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-F:String) [], 
CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What's wrong with it?
I use API's of somewhere else and the problem is the same and it doesn't return any results but errors

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot`: you've been burned by Windows powershell. That's not curl, that's an alias called curl that invokes Invoke-WebRequest for you. Use `curl.exe` to circumvent that silliness.

Comment: @DanielStenberg thank you but I've found when I copy the whole damn code it doesn't give a shit about the \s at the end of codes and it causes the problem , I copied them line by line and the problem vanished successfully, thanks anyway

Comment: That's helpful, but I still need to submit something like this: curl.exe -X PUT { "name": "14 inch Pizza" } http://localhost:8080/demo/menuItem/add  This gives me an error message: curl (3) unmatched brace in URL position 1: {  I don't know how to use spaces in the data.